# SQL UNION multiple COLUMNS into ONE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table in SQL Server 2019:

```
ID Col1 Col2 Col3
1  A    B    C
2  D
3  E    F    G
4  H    I
5  J
```

And I need something like this:

```
ID Col1
1  A
2  B
3  C
4  D
5  E
6  F
7  G
8  H
9  I
10 J
```

The number of columns in the source is not fixed, some rows may have only 1 column but others may have up to like 10, 11, etc. Which functions that I need to apply to achieve the result?

Thanks

Comment: You can't have rows from the same table with a different number of columns? And is your so called "ID" just in fact a row number? Because it doesn't appear to corollate with the source data.

Comment: A quick google for "sql cols to rows" throws up 'UNPIVOT'

Answer (score 3):

You can unpivot using `cross apply` and then order:

```
select row_number() over (order by t.id, v.n) as new_id, v.col
from t cross apply
     (values (t.col1, 1), (t.col2, 2), (t.col3, 3)) v(col, n)
where v.col is not null
order by id, n
```